# how does the result of num2=[0,100,20] get?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've met a question about list comprehension.

```
num1 = [5,10,15]
num2 = [i**2 if i == 10 else i-5 if i < 7 else i+5 for i in num1]
```

why `num2` is `num2 = [0,100,20]`?
How does the result get?

Comment: It's easy to understand as answers below. But why do you need to write list comprehension like this way? I don't think list comprehension should be use here.

Answer (score 1):

Read it as:

```
num2 = [i**2 if i == 10
        else i-5 if i < 7
        else i+5

        for i in num1]
```

- 5 is not equal to 10, but it is less than 7, so it yields 5 - 5 (i.e. 0)
- 10 is equal to 10, so it yields 10 ** 2 (i.e. 100)
- 15 is not equal to 10, not equal to 7, thus we use the default case, so it yields 15 + 5 (i.e. 20)

Answer (score 1):

This list comprehension is exactly equivalent to:

```
num2 = []
for i in num1:
    if i == 10:
        num2.append(i**2)
    else:
        if i < 7:
            num2.append(i-5)
        else:
            num2.append(i+5)
```

Comment: Thanks,bro.You are very nice.